# How to create excel file with multiple sheets using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, model-view-controller

With this I create a excel file, but I have two views that I want to generate two sheets in the same file. Sorry for my english.

```
public ActionResult DescargarExportableDepreciacionTributaria()
{
   System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");          
   Response.AddHeader("Charset", "UTF-8");
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;    filename=re"+ ".xls");
   string style = @"&lt;style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; } </style> ";
   ViewBag.Id = Request.Params["Id"];
   Response.Write(@"<style> TD.text { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>");

   return View("ContenidoExportable");
}
```

Comment: C is not C# is not C! Please add the correct tag.

Comment: Serving HTML and calling it Excel is a recipe for disaster. Use a library that generates proper Excel files.

Comment: It was a quick fix. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/). It may help you create excel files easily using the APIs provided by the library